# What initial value should %ebp take?

Tags: assembly, x86, abi

I have a simple assembly program that attempts to return 3 by storing a temporary variable in memory:

```
.text
    .global _start

_start:
    movl    $2, %ebx
    mov     %ebx, -0x4(%ebp)
    movl    $1, %ebx
    add     -0x4(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    $1, %eax
    int     $0x80
```

However, this gives me a segmentation fault when I run it:

```
$ as out.s -o out.o
$ ld -s -o out out.o
$ ./out
segmentation fault
```

I think this is because I never initialise `%ebp`. My program runs fine if I just use registers and don't access main memory relative to `%ebp`.

What value should it be initialised to? Should a program `malloc` its own stack on startup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On program startup, the `%esp` register is initialised to the top of your stack (remember it grows *downward*), but `%ebp` is not initialised. So you have to do that.

```
_start:
    movl     %esp, %ebp
    subl     $4, %esp
    ... rest of your code
```

This reserves 4 bytes for your local variable, accessed by offset `-4(%ebp)`.

Comment: Actually if all functions are using `%ebp` as a frame pointer, then it would be initialized to the previous frame. But that would be an assumption, of course. 8-)

Comment: This still segfaults. `movl %esp, %ebp` `subl $4, %esp` `movl %ebx, -4(%ebp)` are you sure that's all that's necessary?

Comment: On which instruction, exactly, does your code segfault and what are the values of the relevant registers at that time?

Comment: Aha, looks like it's an issue with running 32-bit code on a machine with a 32-bit kernel. Your answer works perfectly with a 32-bit kernel.

Comment: I get the feeling you meant to type "64" in one of those places.

Comment: Ahem, yes. FWIW, it segfaulted on the third instruction of `movl %esp, %ebp` `subl $4, %esp` `movl %ebx, -4(%ebp)` with %rbp taking the value 0xffffe4f0. I've fixed it by specifying 32-bit ELF to `as` and `ld`.